# Accessing delimiter in Python regular expressions split()

Tags: python, regex

In the python re module, I'm making use of re.split()

```
string = '$aText$bFor$cStack$dOverflow'
parts = re.split(r'\$\w', string)
assert parts == ['Text', 'For', 'Stack', 'Overflow']
```

My question: is it possible to return the instance of the delimiter *at the same time* as the list of parts? I'd like to know if the delimiter was $c, $d, etc. preceding the various parts.

I suppose I could do a findall() call first, but that would mean manually calling positions in a list, which would introduce bugs. That also doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: If you would know what ugly things happen inside re library when you do this you would not consider the manual split as unpythonic anymore.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with `$a`? Should it be returned, or should it be omitted, because it doesn't separate anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the pattern in a capture group, the delimiters appear in the results:

```
>>> string = '$aText$bFor$cStack$dOverflow'
>>> re.split(r'(\$\w)', string)
['', '$a', 'Text', '$b', 'For', '$c', 'Stack', '$d', 'Overflow']
```

Comment: Much simpler than the complex regexp in the other answer.

Comment: @Barmar The `findall`-approach worked reasonably well lately,  when I had to split some keywords by whitespace, but still retain the whitespace... But yeah, you are right. This is much shorter, and does not get more complex as the non-separator part becomes more complicated.